# GL_INVALID_OPERAION in glDrawElements while rendering to Framebuffer from external texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I am trying to render the contents of an external texture (which gets its data from android `MediaCodec`) to a framebuffer with a texture atttachment (first pass) and then using that texture to render to display (second pass)

My overall goal is to do some operation in the shader in the first pass and some more operation in the second pass. But I am getting `GL_INVALID_OPERAION` in the first pass and hence texture associated with the Framebuffer is not populated.

Below is the summary of the code

OpenGL environment initialization

```
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1,frameBufferHandles,0);

GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, bufferHandles, 0);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Utils.VERTICES.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES, Utils.getVertexBuffer(), GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Utils.INDICES.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES, Utils.getIndicesBuffer(), GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

GLES20.glGenTextures(2, textureHandles, 0);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureHandles[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBufferHandles[0]);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandles[1]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GLES20.GL_RGBA,width,height,0,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,null); //width.height are of that viewport and are initialized properly  
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureHandles[1],0);

int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Frame Buffer Incomplete : " + status);
} else
    Log.d(TAG,"Frame Buffer Complete");

GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
```

Vertex Shader setup

```
public static final String DEFAULT_VERTEX_SHADER = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n"
        + "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n"
        + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
        + "void main() {\n"
        + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n"
        + "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n"
        + "}\n";
```

Fragment shader setup

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
uniform sampler2D sTextureSampler;
uniform float r;
uniform int pass;


void main() {
        if(pass == 0) {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
            //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
         }
        else if(pass == 1) {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTextureSampler, vTextureCoord);
         }
}
```

Vertex Attributes and Index buffer are defined like below

```
public static float[] VERTICES = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 1f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 1f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 0f
};

public static int[] INDICES = {
        2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2
};
```

And finally my `draw()` function looks like this

```
protected void draw() {
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mvpMatrix, 0);

    if(mProgram != -1)
        mProgram = createProgram();

    int vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    int uvsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    int texMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
    int mvpMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    int textureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "sTextureSampler");

    int pass = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "pass");


    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(texMatrixHandle, 1, false, texMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0]);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvsHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(uvsHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 3 * 4);

    //Pass 0 - Render to framebuffer , gives GL_INVALID_OPERAION error
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBufferHandles[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(pass, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    //Pass 1 - Render to display
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 2);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(pass, 1);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

}
```

I am guessing it is related to `vTextureCoord`, because if I dont use  `vTextureCoord` and render a constant color to the framebuffer during first pass , then I can read it back during the second pass from the texture associated with the framebuffer.

Comment: Specifically which function returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Comment: DrawElements() with indices requires short buffer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154261/gles2-0-gldrawelements-not-working